# kubectl Dashboard in docker desktop needs proxy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am trying to start kubernetes dashboard in docker for desktop and it's working fine. but all time i need to start `kubectl proxy` and if i close that powershell window then dashboard working stop.

Is there any way to start dashboard without proxy or proxy start all time? how i can access this dashboard in network ?

Comment: You can keep one terminal open for proxy and work on a different one. For Dashboard, a proxy is necessary, if you are configuring with Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to persistently expose the dashboard you have to add a service to your cluster.

Create a yaml file with the following content (Let's call it **dash-serv.yaml**):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-nodeport
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
    nodePort: 32123
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

then run `kubectl apply -f dash-serv.yaml` and test your dashboard access on http://localhost:32123.